# How to export symbol from a package extension in Julia?

Tags: package, julia

With a simple package extension set up like this:

src/Plotting.jl:

```
module Plotting

function plot(x::Vector)
    # Some functionality for plotting a vector here
end

end # module
```

ext/PlottingContourExt.jl (can also be in ext/PlottingContourExt/PlottingContourExt.jl):

```
module PlottingContourExt # Should be same name as the file (just like a normal package)

using Plotting, Contour

function Plotting.plot(c::Contour.ContourCollection)
    # Some functionality for plotting a contour here
end

function newfunction()
   ...
end

end # module
```

How can I `export` `newfunction`? Simply adding `export newfunction` within the `PlottingContourExt` module doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's not possible for extensions to export new names: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/accessing-non-exported-package-extension-functions/109058/5